# Are hidden fees and taxes are form of theft

Tags: halacha

If a merchant or even the government charges you without telling you about a tax or fee is this theft

Comment: I would suppose if they truly didn't tell you, then yes. Usually with these "hidden" fees, there was some mention of it "hidden" away in some paperwork that was probably signed by the agreeing party.

Comment: Most don’t read those or the company says the agreement is subject to change as they please

Comment: True, but seemingly it would be incumbent on the person signing to know what they are signing - even though it can be really difficult and obscure.

Comment: That’s true but again the policy can change, that’s still dishonest especially if the clients never told or told after the fact imo.

Comment: Also in my understanding both parties are suppose to be honest with each other.

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. If someone signs an agreement which clearly (i) specifies fees, or (ii) specifies that fees may be levied or increased in the future because the agreement is subject to change, I don’t see how the author of the agreement can rationally or halachically be regarded as dishonest.

Comment: I already explained that the person was not notified about the fees.

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. I can’t see anywhere where you said that.

Comment: My apologies, I didn’t mean to be rude.  But yes we were not alerted to these new fees or policy changes after so many years